# jquery slider transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am developing a webpage which has two images both set to 512x400px settled in a div
on page load, the first image displays, then on a time delay a second image floats from behind to in front of the first image, the top image is a transparent png,
i have got the jquery working and loks great, the first image loads then after a few seconds the second image appears sliding from the left under the first and over the top of the first image,
the second image is transparent during the transition and i can see the first image all the way upto the poiint that the second image lands directly over the first, then the area turns white, 
i checked firebug and the image on top is definatly png, ???
can anyone help ? 
below is my code 'thats works apart from the final stage transparency bottom image show through'

html

```
<div class="slider">
<ul id="slider1">
<li><img src='<%# /* Graphic ADOR */ AdorRec.FieldValue("ShopExit", Container) %>' alt="Cross-Media Finnished Shopping" width="512" height="400" />
      </li>
    <li>
<img src='<%# /* Graphic ADOR */ AdorRec.FieldValue("MobileOffer", Container) %>' alt="Cross-Media Mobile SMS Offer"  width="512" height="400" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.slider {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 512px;
 height: 400px; 
 border: 8px solid #ffffff;
 border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #333333;
 background:transparent;
}
```

script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1 a:first').css({opacity: 1.0});
    $('#slider1') .cycle({
        fx: 'shuffle',
 //'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight,scrollUp',blindX, blindY, blindZ, cover, curtainX, curtainY, fade, fadeZoom, growX, growY, none, scrollUp,scrollDown,scrollLeft,scrollRight,scrollHorz,scrollVert,shuffle,slideX,slideY,toss,turnUp,turnDown,turnLeft,turnRight,uncover,ipe ,zoom 
        autostop:  1,
        rev:  1,
        speed:  '2000', 
        timeout: 3000 
    });
}); 
</script>
```

please bare in mind i am a very noob at this, and thank anyone for there time in responding
regards matt

Comment: Congratulations on the longest run-on sentence ever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your second image? Here's a fiddle using your code and the example photos from the Cycle plugin site. I can reproduce your error by providing a broken image link for the second photo.

You also might want to consider using `#slider1 {list-style: none;}` to get rid of those bulleted list items

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/N4aJU/